# Unintended knockout binding behavior?

Tags: knockout.js

My scenario:

I have a view with tabs, in two tabs, I am loading a partial view using ajax call.
I wanted to data-bind both of these partial views to local viewmodel.

In both of these partial views, I have an element with the same Id, which is not correct and i planned to fix it, but then i found out a strange behavior.

The element in concern:

```
<div id="listsBar">...</div>
```

The binding done after DOM is ready:

```
$(function () {

    ko.applyBindings(listsViewModel, document.getElementById("listsBar"));

});
```

This was always affecting only the first element, which is probably fine, but now what I needed.

But then, I added a class to the element with the same name as the Id:

```
<div id="listsBar" class="listsBar">...</div>
```

And all of sudden, the binding is applied to both of these elements.

Can anyone explain this? Is it a feature or a bug/hack?

Comment: Do you have two elements with the same ID?

Comment: Yes, the ID of the element is hardcoded in the partial view markup and adding it twice results in two elements with the same ID.
I am aware of the fact that it is not valid HTML, but i would like to discuss the changed behavior of Knockout after adding the class attribute.

Comment: What browser does this happen in?  (This sounds like a *browser* issue rather than a Knockout one).

Comment: @Sean: You might be right, I was unable to reproduce the behavior even in the same browser (which was Chrome). I guess this is a good memento, not to use invalid HTML.